# Resize font size to fit width and height of static UITextView in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a TextView, who's width and height is defined as 80% and 10% respectively according to screen size. and i also have a static text which i want to fit in the TextView according to different screen size. 
I don't want to resize my TextView.I only want to resize FontSize according to different screen size. 
can anyone help me..??

Comment: Why don't you use UILabel instead of UITextView. Because UILabel adjust font size with text increasing but UITextView become scrollable.

Comment: As @Md.MuzahidulIslam said, use a UILabel would be a good choice with setting line number to 0, which could display text in multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

In Swift:

```
    let fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width
textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.max))
let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.max))
var newFrame = textView.frame
newFrame.size = CGSize(width: max(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: newSize.height)
textView.frame = newFrame;
```

Comment: i want to use UITextView, not UITextField

Comment: Oops!
Check the updated answer please!